# Add custom CSS in DKAN website for an image / append a class Name to the HTML element in DKAN

Tags: drupal-8, dkan

[image: Sample Image]

I want to add a CSS for the above image like

```
.img{ float : right }
```

how could I add that in the DKAN 
    If I edit the panel it's showing the options like  in the following image:

[image: Sample Image]

```
or how do I add a class name to the HTML element like in the below example
<a class="right">Image</a>
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To add your own CSS you can:

1. [Create your own Sub-theme](https://dkan.readthedocs.io/en/latest/components/theme.html#creating-a-new-subtheme)
2. Or download and enable the [css_editor](http://drupal.org/project/css_editor) module.

I would only recommend #2 for a limited number of CSS changes.

Comment: This was great..
Thank you @acouch.
But how do I add the class name to the HTML element